# PiHole issues with dual band routers

Tags: routing, dhcp, pi-hole

I have a raspberry pi running pihole as an adblocker AND dhcp server, and a dual band router with two discrete signals send out {ssid1.2G and ssid2.5G}

When the pihole dhcp service is on, my laptop (tried 4 different devices) can only connect to one of the two signals, which ever i try first (i.e if i first connect to ssid1.2G then i can not connect to ssid2.5G and vice versa). This issue only occurs when pihole is running the dhcp server, when the router is runnig dhcp server this is not a problem.

The way around it is to use two discrete MAC addresses on my laptop (one real one cloned) one for each signal. In this way laptop connects fine to both bands.

Laptop has no problem connecting to any other routers, or even to the same dual band router if i use Ethernet.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Even though this problem can be circumvented by having both bands using the same ssid, that is not a desired solution and only a workaround.

{route: netgear D7800, raspberry pi 3B running pihole 4, several devices tried including, laptop/ubuntu, laptop/kde, iphone, samsung tablet}

Comment: You are dealing with limitations of the WiFi protocol (implementation) This is not a Unix issue.

Comment: What happens when you try to switch from ssid1 to ssid2? Do you get any error messages (including in log files)? Do DHCP logs on the Pi show anything? If the router has a log, does it show anything? Trying to find *any* leads because, well, where the DHCP server is ought not matter.

Comment: For instance when tried with my iphone, it never gets assigned an ip and states 'no internet connection' ... From the pihole log during this process theres a back and forth with dnsmasq-dhcp : DHCPDISCOVER(eth0) <MAC ADDRESS> and DHCPOFFER(eth0) <IP ADDRESS> <MAC ADDRESS> and never gets resolved... However with the ssid that it is able to connect, after the above two lines there is eventually DHCPACK(etho) <IP ADDRESS> <MAC ADDRESS> <HOSTNAME>